# Page title disappeared behind body

Tags: css

I created a new ASP.NET MVC application.  The home page looks like this:

[image: Original]

I tried to move the [ Log On ] link to the bottom of the page and got this:

[image: Changed]

What did I do wrong?

EDIT: [Here's][3] the CSS code, [here's][4] the original file, and [here's][5] the changed file.

<sub>(broken links to PasteBin removed)</sub>

Comment: Well... it really depends on what you changed!  Can you post some code, please? :)

Comment: Please give us something more than just images.

Comment: where is your css and html? without that we cannot help. there are many ways this can happen. maybe you're using absolute positioning?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing some code. Did you attempt to move the link to the bottom of the page using CSS, or did you alter the markup?

Comment: For starters, I'd recommend dumping the frameworks and APIs and doing your learning in a text editor. Secondly...we'd have to see your source code to answer the question.

Comment: Probably need to clear a float somewhere - without seeing the HTML / CSS it's impossible to say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, the CSS for your page has some preconceived notions of where and how big each  will be, and you've confused it by moving them around.

In other words, the  containing your main welcome block there does not use absolute positioning, but instead relies on a spacer (the login block) above it for correct spacing.

Comment: Yep.  Because the header element is position relative, without the logindisplay div to push the menucontainer div down, the menucontainer renders on top of the header.  Removing the position:relative element from the #header part of your css should fix the problem.